# How to use range-v3's ranges::actions::transform?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, range-v3

I want to use `ranges-v3` to transform an array in place. I can use
`ranges::transform` successfully, but failed to use `actions::transform`.

```
int arr[]{1, 2, 3};
auto fn = [](auto e) { return e + 1; };
ranges::transform(arr, std::begin(arr), fn); // ok
arr |= actions::transform(std::begin(arr), fn); // error
```

Error Message:

```
fatal error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const ranges::actions::transform_fn'
        arg |= actions::transform(std::begin(arr), std::begin(arr),
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**How to use `actions::transform` in such a case?**

Comment: Sorry, I'm using `range-v3` rather than `std::ranges`.

Comment: Your error message doesn't seem to correspond to the line of code.

Comment: @cigien The error occurs on the last line of code.

Comment: Yes, but the error message text doesn't seem to match up to that line.

Answer (score 3):

In `range-v3`, you would simply do

```
arr |= ranges::actions::transform(fn);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/-9ytoK)